# Can I create User-defined Exceptions in a class, instead of creating for every function when needed in python ? Please Advise

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-requests, python-class

When I created try-except in a class as shown getting an error:
(Reason for creating the user-based exception in class is, I can re-use the exception in any function when needed and I can raise error)

```
class Error(Exception):
   pass
class ValueTooSmallError(Error):
   pass
class ValueTooLargeError(Error):
   pass

import random
class GuessNum(object):
    try:
        def __init__(self):        
            self.number = random.randint(1,50)

        def startGame(self):        
            while True:
               i_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
               if i_num < self.number:
                   raise ValueTooSmallError
               elif i_num > self.number:
                   raise ValueTooLargeError
               break
    except ValueTooSmallError:
       print("This value is too small, try again!")
       print()
    except ValueTooLargeError:
       print("This value is too large, try again!")
       print()
```

But, when I created try-except inside a function script worked fine, but wanted to know why above script was failed. Please advise.

```
number = 10
while True:
   try:
       i_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
       if i_num < number:
           raise ValueTooSmallError
       elif i_num > number:
           raise ValueTooLargeError
       break
   except ValueTooSmallError:
       print("This value is too small, try again!")
       print()
   except ValueTooLargeError:
       print("This value is too large, try again!")
       print()
print("Congratulations! You guessed it correctly.")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class, your try-except block is catching the potentials errors of the definition of your methods. If you want to catch things when executing GuessNum.startGame() you have to place the try-except block in the function.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the response.
Can you please elaborate the statement, if possible with example that would be really helpful for me - "try-except block is catching the potentials errors of the definition of your methods:"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are using try-except wrong. The purpose of try-catch blocks is to handle errors in the runtime, that you might already know. Definition of things, like functions or classes however do not generate error in the run time. If your definition is wrong the interpreter won't even start its job. When you are defining a function, you are just telling it what to do in case it is called. If you define a function that might produce an error, like the following example, the code with function definition will still run:

```
number_of_oranges = 40
total_students = 0
def give_oranges():
        orange_for_each = number_of_oranges/total_students
    return orange_for_each

give_oranges()
```

Here, when you call `give_oranges()` function, it will work most of the times, except when there are no students, meaning `total_students = 0` it will raise a `ZeroDivisionError` error. So we put the statement where we call this function inside a try-except. Not the function definition, mind it, because it just defines the function but doesn't do anything else.

```
number_of_oranges = 40
total_students = 0

def give_oranges():
        orange_for_each = number_of_oranges/total_students
    return orange_for_each
try:
    give_oranges()
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("There are no students!")

give_oranges()
```

This time if there are no students, we will see the except block get executed and "There are no students!" on the screen.

Now that we are clear on exactly where to use try-catch, let's intentionally do a mistake and put the function definition itself inside the try catch, but not the statement where we called it.

```
number_of_oranges = 40
total_students = 0

try:
  def give_oranges():
    orange_for_each = number_of_oranges/total_students
    return orange_for_each
except ZeroDivisionError:
  print("There are no students!")

give_oranges()
```

This time it raises an error as well, but it looks weird:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    give_oranges()
  File "main.py", line 6, in give_oranges
    orange_for_each = number_of_oranges/total_students
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

It almost seems like our except block was not executed as we expected. The error was raised from where the function was invoked. Here is the explanation: When Python interpreter read till the last line, it already knew what give_oranges() method does, and it knew what to do if if this function's definition did not work. The function definition was absolutely correct, so no error was raised and the except block didn't have any ZeroDivisionError to catch. Only when the function was used by us later, the error happened again but this time there was no try-except block to catch the exact statement.

In your case, you are trying to cover some definitions, not where you are actually calling those definitions. The error is raised but not caught by you properly, it's being handled by some builtin mechanisms in Python classes. Sorry for going overboard with the examples and not pointing out the error in your code directly, but now you should have a better understanding of where not to use try-excepts and where to use it properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I now got where to use try catch.
I have one more question, say for example if we have 100 functions in a class and I need try-catch for each function.
Based on current understanding on this topic, I need to create try-catch for each function.

so I got struck here why we are creating 100 try-catches, why can't we define a user based exceptions/ predefined exceptions and raise the error inside every function where its needed. (by this we re-use exceptions).

Sorry for raising multiple questions, want to make sure before I move forward.

Comment: I think you missed the most important point: you should not use try-catch mechanism with any kind of definition. You are not instructing the interpreted to do anything in a definition, are you? You are merely telling it, "Hey, you see the piece of code here? I am going to give it a name `my_function()`. When I call `my_function()` next time, run that specific code please." 

On the other hand, you should use try catch for statements that can actually fail, for example the statements inside the `my_function()` definition. You can have multiple try-catch blocks depending on the group of tasks.

Comment: As for having 100 functions, that's exactly where OOP and other design patterns come in. Obviously the 100 functions can be broken down to a handful of common things, that are building blocks of your code. You need to catch errors in those blocks mostly then you are already covered when you use them in your other methods. Of course, you can still use more try-catches whenever you need, but at least you will have reduced the amount of work and redundancy. If you need more explanation, better ask another question and/or read OOP related books.

Comment: Thanks Ratul for the clarification.

Comment: @VRao you are welcome! If this answer helped, would you kindly mark it as accepted?